# Handeling device rotation

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make my app handle device rotation but it always crashes when I add the below code on the onCreate method from the mainActivity. Here is the error that I am getting. how to I fix this? :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference

```html
2019-09-25 06:58:16.743 10444-10444/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 10444
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onChanged(MainActivity.java:48)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onChanged(MainActivity.java:44)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:289)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsListView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
        contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better place your `LiveData` in a `ViewModel` and observe it in the activity, probably in the `onCreate()` method. Let me show you how can you properly use LiveData in a ViewModel,

**YourViewModel**

```
public class YourViewModel extends ViewModel {

    // Create a LiveData with a List of Contact
    private MutableLiveData<List<Contact>> contactList = new MutableLiveData<>();

    // encapsulated with immutable live data
    public LiveData<List<Contact>> getContactList() {
        return contactList;
    }

    // call this method with a list of new contacts whenever you need to refresh your list
    public void updateContactList(List<Contact> list) {
        contactList.setValue(list);
    }

    // Rest of the ViewModel...
}
```

**YourActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsListView);

        yourViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(YourViewModel.class);

        if(contacts==null) contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
        contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        yourViewModel.getContactList().observe(this, contactObserver);
}


Observer<List<Contact>> contactObserver = new Observer<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Contact> newContacts) {
            if(adapter != null && newContacts != null) {
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.addAll(newContacts);
            }
        }
};
```

Above way you are ensuring the `liveData` is tied with the activity lifecycle and it gets a non null `adapter` in the `onChanged()` method. I hope my answer will help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

when the device is rotated android tears down the activity and recreates it. So the entire life cycle is called.

so save everything in onSavedInstanceState then extract data in onRetainInstanceState

for more details read here :https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

Also here I believe here the issue is setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) is called after contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsListView)

try this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsListView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
    contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

It should work

Comment: i try that, but it still crashes when i runt it the app

Comment: post logcat of the crash

Comment: i have post it above

Comment: seems like you have a method onChanged() which is observing a livedata and you are calling clear on arrayadapter without initializing it .. try putting setContentView above all the initilization and wrap arrayadapter in null check

Answer (score 0):

Handling lifecycle changes is a pain in the butt. I strongly recommend you to take a look at architecture component [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). It will handle orientation changes and other lifecycle changes like a charm. Add together with [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/) and you have a much more robust application that will handle lifecycle changes automatically for you.